# How to avoid Microsoft Teams to act as a multimedia application?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-teams, multimedia

I use Microsoft Teams in my corporate environement.

I have a multimedia keyboard (Logitech MX keys if it matters) that have a play/pause button.

When I press the button, it triggers the Microsoft Teams ring tone (even if no communication is active). Popup contains `Microsoft Teams Notification`:

[image: Microsoft Teams ring tone]

The *right* button in the prompt takes me to my actual multimedia app (Deezer Windows 10 app).

How to avoid MS Teams to be registered as a multimedia app ? Not sure what's the behind the scene regarding this windows feature.

PS: my system is Windows 10 x64 20H2 professional. MS Teams is in the release channel (I guess)

Comment: There is an issue here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/b0668d5e-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2

Upvoting may increase chances of getting it fixed

Answer (score 13):

Start Teams with `-disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling`

eg. `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe -disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling`

or `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"  --process-start-args="-disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling"`

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-and-media-keys/136320bb-7af0-4bdc-8743-56608ff576b2?page=2

Comment: Sounds promising, however the autostart registry entry automatically reverted to its original value. :-( Maybe a new one (and disabling autostart in Teams) would do the trick.

Comment: Indeed, disabling AutoStart and adding a Teams shortcut with relevant args to `shell:startup` can retain the auto start behavior safely.

Comment: For the record: no longer works for me on version 1.5.00.28361 on Windows. The flag is no longer propagated to child processes.

Comment: Yep, no longer working for me. Any other work arounds would be massively appreciated!

Comment: No longer working of Nov 2022. You can hack the .exe with a hex editor and find the string HarwareMediaKeyHandling and look for the closest lonely 01 right of that, and change it to a 00.

Comment: Typo in the above comment, it should be `HardwareMediaKeyHandling`. For more details, see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/media-keys-and-teams-notifications/m-p/1949714

Comment: does not work anymore on windows 10

Comment: What's the solution in 2024? Hex editing no longer works for Teams Classic 1.6.00.33567 (Windows desktop). My only solution was to use online Teams (teams.microsoft.com) as I can instruct Chrome not to hijack my media keys (chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling).

Comment: I think Microsoft fixed it in 2023. I Will try it again in the next weeks.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me on MacOS:

Terminal command: `open "/Applications/Microsoft Teams.app" --args -disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling`

Paste it into a terminal and you are good to go.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @oscar-wieman This stopped working recently (current version 1.5.00.21551). Do you have this issue again, too? Have you figured out why this fix doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @maiermic I'm on version 1.5.00.21551 and it is still working for me.
I wrapped it in an automator application recently and placed it next to my teams application in the task bar: https://imgur.com/a/1eWqEd2

Comment: This solution is no longer working for me. I'll continue to look for a fix and will update my comment when I find one.

Answer (score 2):

I've found on a reddit thread that when you use ctrl or shift and your media keys you will stop teams from intercepting.

This works for me but is a bit annoying as you want to press one button.

So to fix this aswell ive used PowerToys (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) to remap my play/pauze to ctrl+play pause.
[image]

This seems to work for now, i'll update if this ever starts to fail.

EDIT: PowerToys can do alot of other things aswell and is very easy to install, so don't be scared away from it! I've also used it to map the "scroll lock" key of my laptop to play+pause, as it does not have a play/pause button.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I can offer my workaround: When you press play and the Teams ringtone starts along with your music, you can press pause in the Teams Notification popup.

If/when you pause you music again the ringtone *should* not restart.

Comment: Its true until the next call ... actually, it seems that the buttons apply to the latest multimedia app that got focus.

Answer (score 1):

For all Linux Users:
Change the last line in file  /bin/teams
nohup "$TEAMS_PATH" "$@" --disable-namespace-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox **--disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling** > "$TEAMS_LOGS/teams-startup.log" 2>&1 &

(Just add **--disable-features=HardwareMediaKeyHandling** before the > "$Teams_LOGS)

(This is for MS Teams on Arch installed over pacman, might not work for other installs.)