# Keyboard play/pause button not controlling Microsoft Teams

Tags: keyboard, spotify, multimedia, teams

My keyboard's play/pause button played the MS Teams ringtone rather than controlling Spotify. I followed the instruction as listed here: [How to avoid Microsoft Teams to act as a multimedia application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1608218/how-to-avoid-microsoft-teams-to-act-as-a-multimedia-application)

The button seems to have stopped playing ringtone on Teams. However, it would not revert back to controlling Spotify. That means, if I start the computer fresh, run Spotify, the play/pause button would control Spotify. However, after a Teams call, the button would no longer control Spotify. It does nothing. It feels like Teams takes the focus away, but Spotify would not take it back. It holds true even after I close and re-open Spotify again.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the fix for same issue and noticed that it's enough to restart teams in order to return Play button and Spotify functionality. Annoying to do multiple times a day but at least it's faster than restart of whole PC.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I needed to close it via the Task Manager.